# Native HMAC SHA512 support for Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, sha, hmac

I'm trying to implement `HMAC SHA512` encryption to a data string before sending it to the server, as it's their requirement.

I have found many possible solutions for that online, however all of them require including some module or framework.

Isn't `HMAC` and `SHA512` not supported by swift 3.1 natively?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm relatively new to swift.

If it's available, how can I simply encrypt some data using `hmac sha512`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/security/) is the native way to do encryption on Apple devices. You do not need any module or framework, you just [add a bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) and import CommonCrypto:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

You then can compute your HMAC with a simple extension (Swift 4):

```
extension String {

    func hmac(key: String) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), key, key.count, self, self.count, &digest)
        let data = Data(bytes: digest)
        return data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

}
```

Example:

```
let result = "test".hmac(key: "test")
```

Result:

```
88cd2108b5347d973cf39cdf9053d7dd42704876d8c9a9bd8e2d168259d3ddf7
```

If you use Swift on a non-Apple device you indeed need to use an external framework to do encryption.